# Help understanding solution to Geometric series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

> A ball is dropped from a height of 9 metres and rebounds to a height of 6 metres and then on each bounce rises to $\frac{2}{3}$ of the previous height. Find the total distance through which the ball moves before coming to rest.

I understand this question is about geometric series.

Thus $S_{\infty} = \frac{9}{1-2/3} = 27$

But the solution gives *total distance = 2*27-9 = 45m*

Why is not the answer 27m?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ball has to bounce both up and down on every bounce, except the initial drop.  So, you get $2$ times $27$ to double all the drops.  But, you have to subtract $9$ because the initial drop does not include an "up" component.

Comment: wow, I feel silly now.  Thanks joe, for pointing out what was an easy answer.  hehe.